# Laravel MySQL query for This Month Only

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5

Hi i am trying to query my DB and only get values for this current month.

```
 ->whereRaw('CompletedDate LIKE MONTH(now())')
->whereRaw('CompletedDate >= curdate() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH')
->where('CompletedDate', 'Like', 'date("Y-m")')
```

It must just be the values for this month.
If i use the - INTERVAL 1 MONTH , it shows me records for 1 month.
I need only for this current month

Comment: `MONTH(now()` i think it's error here, can u try with `MONTH(now())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do this without using `whereRaw` and take advantage of the Libraries that Laravel packages for you.

```
->where('CompletedData', '>=', \Carbon\Carbon::now()->startOfMonth());
```

As long as your `datetimes` conform correctly, this should be the appropriate solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```html
   SELECT CompletedDate FROM table WHERE CompletedDate >= (CURDATE()-INTERVAL 1 MONTH);
```

IN laravel you use

```html
->whereRaw('CompletedDate >= (CURDATE()-INTERVAL 1 MONTH)')
```